Need help finding an elusive datasheet for CHKC14B5A with manufacturer logo "AB"
The IC in question is labeled as "CHKC14B5A" and appears to be some sort of Bluetooth controller. The only places that seem to sell this particular chip are Chinese websites such as AliExpress, and they don't offer a datasheet. I can't find any manufacturer's website (searching for "A3" doesn't help) and the chip doesn't appear to be available on websites that provide datasheets such as Mouser.


I can't find any manufacturer's website (searching for "A3" doesn't help)

I thought the logo could be "AB".
Found on Reddit:

Need help to find data sheet on these ics:


uy12e4ui25p0iol503kx
The logo that looks like A3 is AB bluetrum. Here is a link to the last time someone asked about a Bluetrum chip
https://old.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/13yub4e/what_is_this_microcontroller/


From the second link:

uy12e4ui25p0iol503kx
The logo is AB Bluetrum, also called Shenzhen Zhongke Lanxun Technology
Bluetrum make a range of bluetooth chips that contain a bluetooth radio and a 32bit microcontroller, usually internal flash for firmware but that could be external.
The i.c.'s are usually marked with part numbers that appear specific to the device they are in, my guess is that device specific firmware is loaded by bluetrum.
There is very little public information.



This is a partial answer since have only identified the manufacturer. From  the above found on Reddit my understanding is that Bluetrum make high volume custom ICs for use in specific products, and the datasheets are not published.
